# prove that there exists $a_{n+1} > a_n$ with $(a_1+\cdots + a_{n+1} )| (a_1^2 +\cdots + a_{n+1}^2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

> Let $1 < a_1<a_2<\cdots < a_n$ be an increasing positive sequence of integers. Prove that there exists $a_{n+1} > a_n$ with $(a_1+\cdots + a_{n+1} )| (a_1^2 +\cdots + a_{n+1}^2)$.

One fact that could come in handy is that if $a,b$ are coprime then $a,b | c\Rightarrow ab | c.$

I think a proof by contradiction or the extremal principle could be useful. Suppose no such $a_{n+1}$ exists and let $(a_1,\cdots, a_n)$ be a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers with $a_1 > 1$ so that one cannot choose $a_{n+1} > a_n$ satisfying $(a_1+\cdots + a_{n+1} )| (a_1^2 +\cdots + a_{n+1}^2)$ and so that $a_n$ is minimal. The goal is to, if possible, construct another such sequence with $a_{n}$ strictly smaller than the previous one, giving the desired contradiction.

If the above approach doesn't work, perhaps an inductive proof might work? For the base case, consider $n=1$. Note that $a_2 = (a_1 - 1)a_1$ works for $a_1 > 2$, since have for $k=a_1 - 1$ that $a_1 + a_2 = (1+k)a_1$ and $(1+k) a_1 = a_1^2 | ((1+k^2)a_1^2).$ For $a_1 = 2,$ we can simply take $a_2 = 6.$ Now assume the result holds for some $n\ge 1$. We need to show the result holds for $n+1$.

Comment: You have posted many interesting problems. May I ask for the source?

Comment: @TheBestMagician FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(a_1%2B%5Ccdots%20%2Ba_%7Bn%2B1%7D)%5Cmid%20(a_1%5E2%2B%5Ccdots%20%2Ba_%7Bn%2B1%7D%5E2)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%241%5Clt%20a_1%5Clt%20a_2%5Clt%5Cldots%5Clt%20a_n%24&p=1), I found the AoPS thread [a^2_1+a^_22+...+a^2_k is divisible by a_1+a_2+...+a_k](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h559166p3252878), where it states the problem source is the "All-Russian olympiad $1995$, Grade $11$, Second Day, Problem $5$".

Comment: @TheBestMagician a lot of the problems come from a Putnam training problem set and those problems happen to come from mathematical olympiads like the Russian olympiad, the USAMO, the Irish olympiad, the IMO shortlist, old IMOs, etc.

Comment: @user3379 gotcha, where can I find this set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For short, let us write $s:=a_1+\cdots+a_n$, $t:=a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2$, and $x:=a_{n+1}$. The task is, given $s$ and $t$, find (suitably large) $x$ such that $x+s$ divides $x^2+t$.

We have $x^2+t=(x+s)(x-s) +s^2+t$. It will therefore be sufficient to find $x$ such that $x+s$ divides $s^2 +t$. Clearly $x=s^2+t-s$ will do. ($x>a_n$ because $x-s=(s-1)^2+t-1>0$ and $s\geqslant a_n$.)